# How do i add more that one Validator argument in Angular 2 form

Tags: validation, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I have tried adding multiple angular validator arguments [i.e  Validators.minLength(8) and Validators.maxLength(12) ] to my form and i cant seem to get it to work...these arguments are attached to the (password and passwordc) instance in the code below. Any help please?

```
   export class signupComponent {
        signupform: FormGroup;
        constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
            this.signupform = this.fb.group({
                firstname: ['', Validators.required],
                lastname: ['', Validators.required],
                account: this.fb.group({
                    email: ['', Validators.required],
                    **password: ['', Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(12), Validators.pattern('[A-Za-z]{5}')],
                    passwordc: ['', Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(12), Validators.pattern('[A-Za-z]{5}')],
                }, { validator: passwordMatcher }),**
                shortbio: ['', Validators.required]
            });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support multiple validators, you have to use the Validators.compose( [ ] ) method that accepts an array of validators. In your case:

```
password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(12), Validators.pattern('[A-Za-z]{5}')])]
```

Comment: This used to be true, but is no longer (IIRC: as of RC3 or RC4). Now, you can simply pass an array of validators – you no longer need `Validators.compose()`. However, `Validators.compose()` *can* still be used, and so I think your answer will solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
password: ['', [Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(12), Validators.pattern('[A-Za-z]{5}')]]
```

This should do the job for you.

Comment: This is **very similar** to the other answer. I think it should rather be a comment on the other answer instead of a seperate answer.

Comment: similar but not same. I have omitted the "compose". It is not necessary. I have simplified it.

Comment: Yeah, that was also [mentioned already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39965847/how-do-i-add-more-that-one-validator-argument-in-angular-2-form/42634393?noredirect=1#comment67223310_39966100), right?